# Are these images of Nicolas Cage as Superman real?

Tags: dc, superman, costume, superman-lives

I recently found out Nicolas Cage was involved in a cancelled Superman movie. I have seen a couple of images of him dressed as Supes
[image: Cage as Superman]
[image: Cage as Superman]

The first image looks almost like a fake but it appear in many places. Are both of these images really from the cancelled "Superman lives/Superman reborn" project?

Comment: Re: first pic: I'd say "almost" is an understatement...!

Comment: This belongs more on Skeptics.SE (they have people really good at detecting fake photos)

Comment: Possibly a better fit on Skeptics, but it's not off-topic here.

Comment: There's a movie about this "lost" movie: http://www.tdoslwh.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The second and third are confirmed real by Nic Cage, himself.**

Empire Magazine conducted [an interview with Cage regarding the photos](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=38155).

> *What was your reaction when the wardrobe images leaked online?*
>
> "There were two images, and there is truth in both. First of all, the first image looked terrible, and the second image looked pretty good. That was a pretty good suit, I’ve got to say. The problem is that it’s unfairly judged. I don’t know who got a hold of it – who in wardrobe who or in the studio or whatever – and leaked it. I don’t understand it. I thought there were laws against this sort of thing, but it's not being judged fairly because you have the lighting that Tim does, or the set, or the shade, or all of that built up. You’ve just got a stark wardrobe shot that’s not given any affection."

While Empire did not post the first image with the interview, it can be reasonably assumed that the "first image" that Cage refers to is the color photo you posted, as those leaks date back to 2009, and the second and third photos you posted are almost always displayed as one.

However, it may not be - since Cage implies that the costumes are the same between the two photos, and they clearly are not (look at the "S" and the sculpted muscles).

Comment: Crikey, I thought the black and white photos looked a bit Photoshopped too. I think he still would have been terribly, terribly wrong in the role.

Comment: *First of all, the first image looked terrible, and the second image looked pretty good. That was a pretty good suit*. It sounds to me like he is addressing both the color image and the two black and white pics, since the two black and white ones have the same suit. I know that he really wanted to play the part of Superman. I think he has a superman tattoo, and has long been known to be a comic book fan.

Comment: @Leatherwing you're right. I had too many windows open and confused a couple of posts I was looking at. Editing now.

Comment: @phantom42. Thanks. I also think he is talking about both color and BW pictures. I could only imagine the awkward silence when they saw him wearing the costume in the studio

Comment: There were multiple costumes. There's also pictures/footage of him wearing just a muscle suit (no logo): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx548HFwCw8 .